# How to assign value to an attribute in object which is pre-initialized using builder?

Tags: java, java-8, getter-setter, lombok, builder

I have class `Employee` as

```
Class Employee{
 private String id = "TempID";
 private String name ;
}
```

When I create an object using new operator , everything works fine .

```
Employee emp = new Employee();
emp.setName("John");
```

Results is

```
emp.getId() -> TempID
emp.getName() -> John
```

However , when I create object using builder like below

```
Employee emp1 = Employee.builder().setName("Mike");
```

Result :

```
emp1.getName() -> Mike
emp1.getId() -> null
```

How can I get value of `emp1.getId()` as `TempId` using builder without setting the value explicitly while creating object i.e. without something like this `Employee.builder().name("Mike").id("TempID");`

I'm using `@Builder` annotation from lombok

Answer (score 2):

You should try this

```
public class Employee {
    @Builder.Default
    private String id = "TempID";
    private String name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set the default values in the no argument constructor.

```
public Employee(){
    this.id = "TempID";
}
```